# Apply parallel processing for "for" loop on defined functions that contain "for" loop as well in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am looking for parallel processing for complicated `for` loop in Python and has no clue how it can be applied to my case. Let say I have a file `input.txt` as below:

```
Group   Process Category        Type    Var1    Var2    Var3
A       3       cat1    type1   86.84   2.913   0.01096
A       3       cat1    type1   103.39  2.835   0.00564
A       3       cat1    type1   109.00  1.478   0.00365
A       3       cat1    type1   107.30  2.979   0.00631
A       3       cat1    type1   123.09  2.424   0.00531
A       3       cat1    type1   111.98  7.462   0.00332
A       841     cat2    type2   87.62   3.049   0.01195
A       841     cat2    type2   87.40   4.781   0.00930
A       841     cat2    type2   88.53   3.025   0.00697
A       841     cat2    type2   85.84   2.703   0.00697
```

Ideally, I want to groupby `Group`, `Process`, `Category` and `Type`, and do some calculations on `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3` using four defined functions, which three of them contain `for` loop as well. The `output` from the implementation is as below:

```
   Group   Type  Process Category        Var1       Var2       Var3
0     A  type1        3     cat1  101.207332  13.997181  106.30899
1     A  type2      841     cat2   87.431341   3.584393  106.30899
```

The complete code for implementation is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dplython import X, sift, DplyFrame, mutate, select
from plydata import define, group_by, summarize

def weightedMean(data):
        length = len(data['Var1'])
        if length == 1:
                mx = data['Var1']
                return(length)
        else:
                mx = data['Var1'][0]
                nx = data['Var3'][0]
                for i in range(1,length):
                        my = data['Var1'][i]
                        ny = data['Var3'][i]
                        nx = nx + ny
                        mx=(mx*nx+my*ny)/(nx+ny)
                return(mx)

def summation(data):
        length = len(data['Var3'])
        cx = data['Var3'][0]
        for i in range(1,length):
                cy = data['Var3'][i]
                cx = cx + cy
        return(cx)

def sd_c(x_m, x_s, x_n, y_m, y_s, y_n):
        al = x_n+y_n
        tmp_sd = al*((x_n-1)*(x_s*x_s)+(y_n-1)*(y_s*y_s))+y_n*x_n*(x_m-y_m)*(x_m-y_m)
        var = tmp_sd/(al*(al-1))
        std = np.sqrt(var)
        return(std)

def sd_pooled(data):
        length = len(data['Var1'])
        if length == 1:
                mx = data['Var1']
                return(length)
        else:
                mx = data['Var1'][0]
                sx = data['Var2'][0]
                nx = data['Var3'][0]
                for i in range(1,length):
                        my = data['Var1'][i]
                        sy = data['Var2'][i]
                        ny = data['Var3'][i]
                        sx = sd_c(mx, sx, nx, my, sy, ny)
                        nx = nx + ny
                        mx = (mx*nx + my*ny)/(nx + ny)
                return(sx)

dat = pd.read_csv("input.txt",sep="\t")

dat_name = dat.loc[:,'Type'].unique()
dat = DplyFrame(dat)

out = pd.DataFrame([])
for i in range(len(dat_name)):
        df = (dat >>
                sift(X.Type == dat_name[i]) >>
                mutate(Var3 = X.Var3*3021) >>
                sift(X.Var2 < 50))
        out = out.append(df)
        out_grouped = out.groupby(['Group', 'Type', 'Process', 'Category'])
        init = []
        mean = []
        stdv = []
        freq = []
        kmer = []
        for name, group in out_grouped:
                group = pd.DataFrame(group).reset_index()
                nm = name
                wm = weightedMean(group)
                sd = sd_pooled(group)
                fq = summation(group)
                init.append(nm)
                mean.append(wm)
                freq.append(fq)
                stdv.append(sd)
        init = pd.DataFrame(init)
        mean = pd.DataFrame(mean)
        freq = pd.DataFrame(freq)
        stdv = pd.DataFrame(stdv)
        init.rename(columns={0:'Group',1:'Type',2:'Process',3:'Category'}, inplace=True)
        mean.rename(columns={0:'Var1'}, inplace=True)
        stdv.rename(columns={0:'Var2'}, inplace=True)
        freq.rename(columns={0:'Var3'}, inplace=True)

output = pd.concat([init.reset_index(drop=True), mean, stdv, freq], axis=1)
```

How do I apply parallel processing using multi cores for this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do I get ```count``` for each row? your summation and weighted mean function refer to a key called ```count``` , Can you give a high level view of how one might compute this value for each row from ```Var1```, ```Var2``` and ```Var3```

Comment: @ThalishSajeed My apologies.`count` is actually `Var3`. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: So you want to group the table on group , process , category and type and then apply your functions  on each row. Am I Correct? How do I aggregate the var variable when grouping? Do I just sum them?

Comment: I already managed to `groupby` and applied the functions. I got a list of `dat_name` from `Type` and ran by subsetting the data by `for` loop. I wish to apply **parallel processing** for this `for` loop but I couldn't find a way to run for a complicated `for` loop. I was wondering ff there is any available module and function equivalent to `%dopar%` in `foreach` and `doParallel` R packages? I am sorry for confusing question.

Comment: There are better ways to achieve parallel processing. I can suggest them once I know if I have understood your question correctly. can you reply if I have understood the question correctly.

Comment: Btw For loops are really inefficient in pandas. You need to use map , apply applymap or dask. There are ways to use multiprocessing when using the apply syntax.

Comment: @ThalishSajeed Yes you got it right and thanks for your help. Do I have to use `map` for every function?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack here so please bear with me.

I have stored the dataset into a pandas dataframe by the name `dat`

```
    Group   Process Category    Type    Var1    Var2    Var3
0       A      3    cat1       type1    86.84   2.913   0.01096
1       A      3    cat1       type1    103.39  2.835   0.00564
2       A      3    cat1       type1    109.00  1.478   0.00365
3       A      3    cat1       type1    107.30  2.979   0.00631
4       A      3    cat1       type1    123.09  2.424   0.00531
5       A      3    cat1       type1    111.98  7.462   0.00332
6       A      841  cat2       type2    87.62   3.049   0.01195
7       A      841  cat2       type2    87.40   4.781   0.00930
8       A      841  cat2       type2    88.53   3.025   0.00697
9       A      841  cat2       type2    85.84   2.703   0.00697
```

The next step was to group the table on `Process`, `Category` and `Type` (I have omitted `Group` for now since `Group` seems to have only 1 unique value)

I have used `.sum()` since that is how you said you wanted the `Var` variables to be aggregated during the grouping.

`out_grouped = dat.groupby(['Type', 'Process', 'Category']).sum()`

This is what the dataframe would look like after grouping -

```
                                     Var1   Var2    Var3
Type    Process Category            
type1   3         cat1               641.60 20.091  0.03519
type2   841       cat2               349.39 13.558  0.03519
```

The next step is that you want to apply functions on each row of this aggregation -

your functions must be designed so that the computation relies only on each atomic row of the dataframe.

your weighted mean function should not peek into other rows for computation. If you do have a requirement - then make those values available in each row of the dataframe as a pre-processing step.

```
def weightedMean(data):
    l = data['Var1']
    m = data['Var2']
    n = data['Var3']
    wm = l*m*n/l+m+n
    return wm
```

The last step is applying the `weightedMean` function across each row of the dataframe.

This is how to do it on a single core-

`out_grouped["weighted_mean"] = out_grouped.apply(weightedMean, axis=1)`

To distribute this computation across multiple cores - you can make use of the [DASK API](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/use-cases.html).

P.S I'm pretty sure I have made some errors in the way I have interpreted your problem statement. So feel free to correct me and I'll modify the code appropriately.

This is how the dataframe will look like after the apply function -

```
                              Var1      Var2    Var3    weighted_mean
Type    Process Category                
type1   3       cat1          641.60    20.091  0.03519 20.833192
type2   841     cat2          349.39    13.558  0.03519 14.070296
```

Comment: Hi Thalish. Thanks for the answer. However, what I am actually looking for is to apply **parallel multiprocessing** to several defined functions. I have seen examples to apply it to each individual defined functions but can I run the parallel multiprocessing to several functions at one time?

Comment: When you apply multiprocessing. You can define on how many cores you want to run the code. The way to go is apply one function on your entire dataframe using all the cores, store the result. Apply the second function and so on.

I mean sure you can apply the same paradigm to several functions. Just have a helper function that calls all your other functions and use apply on that helper function.